# Do `Signature` headers have real benefits?

Tags: authentication, digital-signature, security-theater

I'm working with an HTTPS API that requires me to include a `Signature` header, the signature is calculated as `codeBase64(hmacWithSha384(key, body))`. I'm wondering if it provides any real-life benefits or if it's just security theatre, as opposed to providing simple API keys

My thinking process:

- an attacker shouldn't be able to modify the request body anyway
- nobody should be able to read the headers anyway, so putting the API key in the header wouldn't leak it
- similar services (e.g. stripe) operate with API keys in auth headers and they seem to be fine

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between a signature and encryption?

Comment: @schroeder yes, I only refer to encryption because then it should be fine to include secrets in the HTTPS headers. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think it does in the way that this header can't prove anything other than that I do have access to the key (which was provided by the service). I would see the benefit with a public/private key pair, but hmac is symmetric

Comment: @hangyas: The TLS endpoint is not necessarily the same system/app which processes the request and checks the API key. For example load balancers might be the TLS endpoint, but not the application backend. It might therefore make sense to not expose the API key directly inside the request, i.e. being only protected by TLS.